# How to get Azure Devops runtime parameters from REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, azure-pipelines

If there is a pipeline with variables configured, call to

`GET https://{host}/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}`

or `GET https://{host}/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}`

returns list of that variables.

But in case of runtime parameters (which are configured in YAML) like this

```
parameters:
- name: testParameter
  displayName: Parameter
  type: string
  values:
  - 'test1'
  - 'test2'
```

non of endpoints above return this parameter.

While tracing network calls of UI page of run pipeline, found call to:

`POST https://{host}/{organization}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/{projectId}`

which returns templateParameters which actually are runtime parameters. But looks like this API is hidden so I don't want to use it. Is there any other way to get runtime parameters using official API?

Comment: `GET https://{host}/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs` - try this, it will give you the last value set for the parameters in `templateParameters`

Comment: It gives me a list of previous builds but there is no passed parameters. Also pipeline config may be changed and this information will be obsolete.

Comment: What is your use case for this? Do you want to pass in the templateParameters to the pipeline and run it?

Comment: In general - yes, but firstly I need to know what parameters to pass

Comment: wouldn't you know what runtime parameters your pipeline has exposed? like in the above example `testParameter` would need to be passed in with some value. This is be achieved with a simple PowerShell script